# How to order "top rated" results by date and meta key?

Tags: wp-query

[image]

Hello. I want to order the top rated results by post date + meta key so it only shows newest post + full rating/score

Here is my code

```
<div class="featbox">
<h3 class="sidetitl "> Top Rated Movies </h3>
<?php
$rate_query =  new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'movies', 'orderby' => 'date', 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'wtf_rscore', 'posts_per_page'=>'14' ) );
while ( $rate_query->have_posts() ) : $rate_query->the_post();
?>
```

Please help me, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off - I can see you're trying to add `meta_value` as an `orderby` param, but you've actually added as it an array entry - this is why formatting and indentation is important!

```
$rate_query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'      => 'movies',
    'orderby'        => 'date meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'       => 'wtf_rscore', 
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
]);
```